# Select a date, loop through column then move value to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet with days of the year in the row 2, I would like to search this range and find a date via an inputbox, then loop through that column with the selected date to find all cells with a  particular letter in it ("E" for instance), then take the corresponding names in column A and copy it to another sheet creating a list of names in the new sheet.

I have code for the date selection via a inputbox and that works well but Im having difficulties with the remainder.

```
Sub Worksheet_Find()

    Dim strdate As String
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim lReply As Long

    strdate = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter a Date to Locate on This Worksheet", _
            Title:="DATE FIND", Default:=Format(Date, "Short Date"), Type:=1)

    If strdate = "False" Then Exit Sub
    strdate = Format(strdate, "Short Date")

    On Error Resume Next

    Set rCell = Cells.Find(What:=CDate(strdate), After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas _
        , LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

   rCell.Select

   On Error GoTo 0

   If rCell Is Nothing Then
       lReply = MsgBox("Date cannot be found. Try Again", vbYesNo)
       If lReply = vbYes Then Run "FindDate":
   End If

End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

wingnut74

Comment: It will help you to get an answer if you rephrase it like a question at the end. Like "how can I get the remainder?"

Answer (score 0):

I would expect you do a simple Do While loop:

```
Do While Len(Sheets("SheetName").Cells(i, rCell.collumn).value)>0
    'do your if condition here... (if Sheets("SheetName").Cells(i, rCell.collumn).value Like "*E*" or use Instr() function
    i=i+1
Loop
```

something like that... if you are not sure how to use loops, look that up in some tutorials